# querying nvarchar fields in a table pauses part way through

Tags: sql-server, performance, corruption

I have a problem with one of the tables in my database. If I do a select * from table, the query will grab the first hundred or so records in under a second, pause for a few seconds, grab the next 600 or so and then not go any further (the query keeps processing but no more records are fetched. It consistently stops after record 718 - even if I let it run for more than 10 minutes.

Notes:

- I've been using this table for quite some time in this database and copies of it in other databases without any problems.
- I can do a select * on any other table.
- I can do a count(*) on this table.
- I can do a select field from this table for any non nvarchar field.

I'm assuming that there is some kind of corruption going on but DBCC CHECKDB(MyDB) WITH NO_INFOMSGS isn't reporting anything.

Comment: Does it need to be indexed?

Comment: The table has indexes, but not on any of the nvarchar fields. Besides, I don't think indexing is an issue since (a) it's a select * without any ordering, filter or joins; (b) there are only 857 records with 51 columns - it's a small table; and (c) it rapidly brings back results for most of the records and then goes several minutes without bringing back the rest.

Comment: Is the connection being closed in between calls?   Are you using a connection pool?

Comment: The original query ran from an application, but all the other tests I've done have been executed in SSMS.

Comment: Are statistics up to date?  and are you seeing any resource waits when running the query?

Comment: Insert expletive of choice. I had an uncommitted update statement in another SQL window that was locking a record in that table. Everything works now that I've fixed that.

Comment: Brad, your question is what revealed the answer, if you could write that up as an answer I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by a record lock on the table - in another SSMS window I had another uncommitted transaction that was locking the record. Once that was committed the queries worked successfully.

Credit to Brad D for setting me on the right path.

FYI: exec sp_who; exec sp_who2 or exec sp_lock would have identified the wayward process.